# UITableView's subview never shows up

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, swift, uikit

I'm trying to add a subview to `UITableView` (yes, not `UITableViewCell` but `UITableView`). And it is never shown. At first I thought that I add it too early and it gets covered by the cells, but that's not true. I tried to add it with a delay when all cells are already added, i tried bringing it to front, i tried adding the view to tableview's subviews, but all in vain, it just never shows up. Here is my code:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    func c()
    {
        var v:UIView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0))
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        v.center = CGPointMake(40.0, 40.0)
        tableView!.addSubview(v)
        tableView!.bringSubviewToFront(v)
    }

    delay(5.0, closure: c)
}
```

Any ideas? The problem is obviously related to Swift because in Objective-C it doesn't reproduce

Comment: Your code worked for me (the green view showed up after a 5 second delay). Are you sure that tableView is not nil? It also worked, if I got rid of the delay and moved the code you have inside func c() into viewDidLoad (in Swift).

Comment: @rdelmar hmmm, that's interesting. i'm 100% sure the table view is not nil, ok, thank you

Answer (score 1):

#### First

I try this in a `UITableViewController`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view];
}
```

It works

[image: sample]

#### Second

I notice that you add a view with `CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0)`. So the view might under the navigation bar if you have one in your viewcontroller

Comment: probably it's something with Swift, because Objective-C works ok